# How to determine which job is executed most often in Jenkins?

Tags: xml, api, xslt, hudson, jenkins

Do you know how to determine each job execution count for given period?

Comment: Why do you require this information? Do you have a large number of jobs?

Comment: @Bernard yes I have about 100 jobs on Jenkins server. I would like to know which are used more than others.

Comment: You still haven't said why you need to know? Curiosity? Housekeeping?

Comment: @Bernard Housekeeping mostly. I need this information to set priorities on other tasks. Why do you ask?

Comment: It helps us determine what you are looking to achieve and thus we can provide you with better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XPath expression will return the number of builds with timestamps between `1329817773921` and  `1329834427888` for job *MyJobName*:

```
http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=string(count(/hudson/job[name='MyJobName']/build[timestamp>=1329817773921 and timestamp<=1329834427888]))
```

The timestamps themselves are the standard number of milliseconds [since the epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

The following XPath can be used to determine the number of different jobs on the server:

```
http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=string(count(/hudson/job))
```

The following XPath can be used to determine the name of the third job on the server:

```
http://[jenkins_server]/api/xml?depth=2&xpath=/hudson/job[3]/name/text()
```

You can write a short shell script that combines those queries executed via `wget` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on @malenkly_scot answer I managed to retrieve statistic information about jobs count during last month.

Below the steps:

- First retrieve data from Jenkins (thanks @malenkly_scot!)

> http://buildcontrol//api/xml?depth=2&xpath=%28/hudson/job[build[timestamp%3E=1328054460000%20and%20timestamp%3C=1330560060000]]%29&wrapper=jenkins

You can use this page to resolve timestamp values: [Epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)

- Apply xslt transformation to count jobs

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>       xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
>
> <xsl:template match="/">
>       name;count;
>       <xsl:apply-templates select="/jenkins/job"></xsl:apply-templates>
>     </xsl:template>
>
> <xsl:template name="job" match="/jenkins/job">
>       <xsl:apply-templates select="displayName"/>;<xsl:value-of select="count(./build)"/>
>       <xsl:text>;
>     </xsl:text>
>     </xsl:template>
>
> </xsl:stylesheet>

- Paste the result of the transformation to excel, sort and there it is :)